# Http callout Null check error in response

Tags: httprequest

Error

> Attempt to de-reference a Null object.

in my below httpcallout I get above error for line

```
if(xroot.getChildElement('State', null).gettext() != null)
```

my callous code looks as below .

```
        resp = res.getBody();
        system.debug('res :' + resp); // resp == resXML
       Dom.Document docx = new Dom.Document();
        docx.load(resp);
        system.debug('Docx' + docx);
        Dom.XmlNode xroot = docx.getRootElement();
        if(xroot.getChildElement('ZipCode',null)!= null){
           if(xroot.getChildElement('State', null).gettext() != null){
              String state = xroot.getChildElement('ZipCode',null).getChildElement('State',null).getText();
                c.MailingState = state;
                system.debug('State'+ state);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods can't be called on a null reference; it looks like getChildElement('State',null) is returning a null value, so you should check that first:

```
Dom.XmlNode stateNode = xroot.getChildElement('State',null);
if(stateNode != null && stateNode.getText() != null) {
```

---

Based on the additional comment, it looks like you need to read the ZipCode node to get to the State:

```
Dom.XmlNode zipNode = xroot.getChildElement('ZipCode',null),
    stateNode = zipNode == null? null: zipNode.getChildElement('State',null);
if(stateNode != null && stateNode.getText() != null) {
```

Comment: It is not returning Null for state. Look at the response that I get. 
<CityStateLookupResponse><ZipCode ID="0"><Zip5>08873</Zip5><City>Somerset</City><State>NJ</State></ZipCode></CityStateLookupResponse>

Comment: @Ricky state is a child of ZipCode, not the root element. You'll need to get the ZipCode node first.

Comment: I am getting this error when I enter your modify answer."Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void get(String, NULL) from the type dom.XmlNode"

Comment: @Ricky Yeah, it should have been getChildElement instead of get.

Comment: Hey Great that worked for me. One last question if I want to get city from the same response I believe I just need to add this line "cityNode = zipNode == null? null: zipNode.getChildElement('City',null);" But when I add that I get error saying variable cityNode does not exist.can you explain?

Comment: @Ricky I used the `,` operator to declare multiple variables of the same data type; you need to change the `;` to a `,` to continue declaring variables of the same type.